# Why are my HAML named routes empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, link-to

I'm trying to create some pages in HAML, which are partly working. The HTML that it produces is correct, apart from one thing. Where I have:

```
%ul#menu 
  %li 
    = link_to 'Home', root_url
```

I am expecting to get back:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Instead, it is producing:

```
<a href>Home</a>
```

Upon looking into it further, it seems that all of my named routes are simply returning a blank string and not the route they are meant to. This is happening on all of them not just root.

If I try changing it to a made-up name, something like 'test_path' then, as I expect, I get an error saying the method doesn't exist, so it's not a case of not being able to find it, it's simply not returning anything.

In the Rails console I am able to get the correct route so I know it's working, and `rake routes` gives me:

```
about        /about(.:format)                   welcome#about
contact      /contact(.:format)                 welcome#contact
faq          /faq(.:format)                     welcome#faq
plans        /plans(.:format)                   welcome#plans
root         /                                  welcome#index
```

Can anyone help as this is a pretty major issue and makes it pretty hard to keep developing if I can't generate links to anything

Comment: That's not normal... And nothing you've posted would tell us why.  Are you using any wierd gems or plugins that might interfere with routing?

Comment: maybe if you can put your project on github or any other services someone can have a look at it

Comment: Actually... What happens if you use `root_path` instead of `root_url`?

Comment: Exactly the same thing. _path or _url returns nothing. I can't think of any gems that would break it. It was originally working when I was using ERB but now It's not working with ERB again :( I've commented out the newest gems I've added before it stopped working and it's still not working. I can't really make a public repo as it's for another company so is private :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out what it was.

The application I'm working on uses BaseCamp-style subdomains for an organisation.

Following Railscast [#221 Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) on implementing subdomains, I had created the `url_for` method as shown, however simply missed the `super` keyword so it was never generating the URL.

Comment: When Stack Overflow allows it, award yourself the answer.

Comment: Will do. So annoying you have to wait 2 days! :(